# Function to filter values in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, filter, pyspark

I'm trying to run a for loop in PySpark that needs a to filter a variable for an algorithm.

Here's an example of my dataframe df_prods:

```
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|ID        |        NAME        |           TYPE     |
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    7983  |SNEAKERS 01         |            Sneakers|
|    7034  |SHIRT 13            |               Shirt|
|    3360  |SHORTS 15           |               Short|
```

I want to iterate over a list of ID's, get the match from the algorithm and then filter the product's type.

I created a function that gets the type:

```
def get_type(ID_PROD):
    return [row[0] for row in df_prods.filter(df_prods.ID == ID_PROD).select("TYPE").collect()]
```

And wanted it to return:

```
print(get_type(7983))
Sneakers
```

But I find two issues:
1- it takes a long time to do that (longer than I got doing a similar thing on Python)
2- It returns an string array type: ['Sneakers'] and when I try to filter the products, this happens:

```
type = get_type(7983)
df_prods.filter(df_prods.type == type)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [Sneakers]
```

Does anyone know a better way to approach this on PySpark?

Thank you very much in advance. I'm having a very hard time learning PySpark.

Comment: instead simply collect .. do collect().head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little adjustment on your function. This returns the actual string of the target column from the *first record* found after filtering.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def get_type(ID_PROD):
  return df.filter(col("ID") == ID_PROD).select("TYPE").collect()[0]["TYPE"]

type = get_type(7983)
df_prods.filter(col("TYPE") == type) # works
```

I find using `col("colname")` to be much more readable.

About the performance issue you've mentioned, I really cannot say without more details (e.g. inspecting the data and the rest of your application). Try this syntax and tell me if the performance improves.

Comment: It worked, thank you! It take 9s to filter, which is longer than I was getting with Pandas. I understand that i has to do with the dataframe being in memory in Pandas and not in Pyspark, but I lack the knowledge in Pyspark to make it faster.